# STM32F042K6U6 BOOT0 pin? Can not understand how to program it with DFU mode

Tags: stm32, embedded

I'm planning out a board and trying to make sure of how to go into DFU mode and the actual program on a STM32F042K6U6. I want to use the K6U6 for the small size, which also rules out using STLINK to program it (I don't want to use the board space to connect the header).

I've used the K6T6 variant before which has a dedicated BOOT0 pin which I pull low to run my program.

The K6U6 doesn't appear to have a dedicated BOOT0 pin, but, if I'm reading the datasheet correctly, apparently PB8 or PF11 can be configured as BOOT0. But I don't see how.

I'm using ST's CubeIDE btw.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.tag-connect.com/catalog/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All packages have a pin having the `BOOT0` role which **must** at reset be correctly driven for the desired startup mode, regardless if you ever plan to change that or not.

If the pin is also available as a GPIO then you would need to keep your GPIO usage compatible with an approach such as having a pulling resistor that sets the state at reset, after which you are free to override the pulling resistor with a different input or output state - of course you must keep in mind the power cost of of asserting a signal against a pulling resistor.

That said it would be a **severe mistake** to design yourself a board with no means of access to the two key SWD signals, and really nRST and a UART too.  Take them only as far as pads you can solder under a microscope or preferably hit with a pogo fixture, but don't skip them.  There are just too many development possibilities you give up if you do.

Comment: While I agree with Chris' sentiments, you don't have to tie the boot0 pin atall. You can set the boot1 option bit to achieve the same effect-see page 52, section 2.5 of the reference manual rm0091.

Comment: I have done this with an l432kcu6, so I know this works in practice for another device type...